# object property not accessible in IE

Tags: javascript

Im using $.xml2json to transform a soap response into json. This working in all browsers except when I enable compatibility mode in IE11 (which I think virtualize older versions of IE)

with compatibility mode enable, if I do:

```
$.xml2json(soapResponse)
[object Object]
   {
      soapenv:Body: [object Object] {...},
      xmlns:soapenv: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
      xmlns:xsd: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
      xmlns:xsi: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   }
```

Notice that the Body property is written with soapenv: before it.

If I try to access the Body property like this:

```
body_prop = $.xml2json(soapResponse).Body.content
[object Error]  Impossible to obtain the property " Body " of a null or undefined reference 

console.log($.xml2json(soapResponse).Body);
>>> undefined
```

Is there a way to access the Body property in such object?

Comment: No, you can't access `body` in a variable that is `null` or `undefined`. The plugin probably doesn't return what you think it does.

Comment: But if you look in the first code block... the object returned by $.xml2json has a soapEnv:Body which I can open the tree. what is that if not a property?

Comment: Looks like something that is namespaced, most likely an XML node ?